# Mac OS X Lion Hibernate

Tags: macos, hibernate

I do "hibernation" whenever I'm done with my MAC, but every once in a while it doesn't come back from hibernation, this is what OS X tells me, can someone translate that for me? or suggest anything useful I can do to prevent my OS X crashing?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  103947 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    AFB41B23-D32F-45B6-90A6-99258031E0DF

Wed Apr 11 19:00:35 2012
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8000612859): "Hibernate restore error e00002bf"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.24.23/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:2782
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f16c3bb0 : 0xffffff8000220702 
0xffffff80f16c3c30 : 0xffffff8000612859 
0xffffff80f16c3cf0 : 0xffffff80002ca4b4 
0xffffff80f16c3d50 : 0xffffff7f81fd64bf 
0xffffff80f16c3d80 : 0xffffff7f81fd9604 
0xffffff80f16c3da0 : 0xffffff800064bb80 
0xffffff80f16c3de0 : 0xffffff8000664b6b 
0xffffff80f16c3e20 : 0xffffff800062b9aa 
0xffffff80f16c3e70 : 0xffffff8000632d99 
0xffffff80f16c3eb0 : 0xffffff8000628aa4 
0xffffff80f16c3ef0 : 0xffffff8000628c4b 
0xffffff80f16c3f30 : 0xffffff80006386c0 
0xffffff80f16c3f70 : 0xffffff8000638564 
0xffffff80f16c3fb0 : 0xffffff8000820057 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(1.4)[1DA2C084-3877-3947-8C3F-AEF7265C4901]@0xffffff7f81fcc000->0xffffff7f82023fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4A5A4624-7A52-3EA0-BB8D-5B265B086727]@0xffffff7f80804000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.8)[F63D4ABE-42DA-33EF-BADD-3415B0CB0179]@0xffffff7f80877000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
11D50

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7B6546C7-70E8-3ED8-A6C3-C927E4D3D0D6
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 22854499222596
last loaded kext at 728405787952: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs   9.8 (addr 0xffffff7f81123000, size 356352)
last unloaded kext at 624593619818: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.15 (addr 0xffffff7f807c5000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.Symantec.kext.SAVAPComm 11.0.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.1.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.1.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.1.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.1.10
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.3
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   2.4.4
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOn   5.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 9.8
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   6.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.4d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.1.7f9
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.0.16
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000    7.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   513.20.19
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.1.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.0.8b2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 167.3.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   167.3.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAVBAudio  1.0.0d11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.3f12
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1.0.0d22
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc6
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.1.7f9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.1d8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller    7.1.8
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.3f12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.3f12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.3f12
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 227.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 403
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 1.7.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   412.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.0d5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.4
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D3130363636434C392D344742535100
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D3130363636434C392D344742535100
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.19)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.3f12, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST93205620AS, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```